# Clear CATiledLayers Cache When Changing Images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, quartz-graphics

I have a UIScrollView with a single subview, a UIView backed by a CATiledLayer.  All is working well with one exception:  when I change images from one to another the CATiledLayer caches the previous images zoom levels.  Scrolling around then displays the old image for a split second before the updated image loads.

Is there any way to totally clear out the CATiledLayer's cache so it doesn't show old images?  The CATiledLayer obviously knows that the backing image changed because it asks it's delegate for new tiles...

Answer (score 25):

I think you are making this a little more complicated than it needs to be.  I believe all you have to do is set the contents of your CATiledLayer to nil.

```
myCATiledlayer.contents = nil.
```

Comment: Right in the soca it warns that modifying a CATiledLayers contents will effectively turn it into a regular CALayer and sure enough it does. An Apple employee did however tell me a trick:  if you call setNeedsDisplay on the recently-converted-back-to-CALayer-CATiledLayer then it will *magically* turn back into a CATiledLayer.

Comment: I had the same problem as prime31 did, and this solution worked great! I called myCATiledlayer.contents = nil before calling [myCATiledlayer setNeedsDisplay], and it did the job. Yay!

Comment: Make sure that you are not setting the layer contents to nil when the layer is still drawing, because the app will crash.

Comment: @Khomsan, on the contrary, i see iOS waiting for all threads to finish drawing before it sets contents to nil.

Comment: @steipete OK maybe my app crash for some other reasons, sorry if my information is incorrect.

Comment: In the CATiledLayer header there is a disclaimer * Note: do not attempt to directly modify the `contents' property of
 * an CATiledLayer object - doing so will effectively turn it into a
 * regular CALayer. */

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)invalidate
{
    CATiledLayer *tiledLayer = (CATiledLayer *)[self layer];

    tiledLayer.tileSize = CGSizeMake(93,93);//Set a different tile size
    tiledLayer.tileSize = CGSizeMake(92,92);//Restore original tile size
}
```

This works for me.