# Redrawing UIScrollView contents after every zoom

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, ios

I have a `UIView` inside a `UIScrollView`.  Whenever the `UIScrollView` zoom changes, I want to redraw the entire `UIView` at the new zoom level.

In iOS < 3.2, I was doing this by resizing the `UIView` within the `UIScrollView` to make it the new size, and then setting the transform back to Identity, so that it wouldn't try to resize it further.  However, with iOS >= 3.2, changing the identity also changes the `UIScrollView`'s zoomScale property.

The result is that whenever I zoom (say 2x), I adjust the embedded `UIView` to be the appropriate size, and redraw it.  However now (since I reset the transform to Identity), the `UIScrollView` thinks its once again at zoomScale 1, rather than zoomScale 2.  So if I have my maxZoomScale set at 2, it will still try zooming further, which is wrong.

I thought about using the `CATiledLayer`, but I don't think this is sufficient for me, since I want to redraw after every zoom, not just at certain zoom thresholds like it tries to do.

Does anyone know how to do the proper redrawing of the `UIView` on a zoom?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tom,

Your question is a bit old, but I came up with a solution for this, so I figured I'd put in an answer in case it helps you or anyone else. The basic trick is to reset the scroll view's `zoomScale` to 1, and then adjust the `minimumZoomScale` and `maximumZoomScale` so that the user can still zoom in and out as expected.

In my implementation, I've subclassed `UIScrollView` and set it to be its own delegate. In my subclass, I implement the two delegate methods you need for zooming (shown below). contentView is a property I added to my `UIScrollView` subclass that in order to give it the view that actually displays the content.

So, my init method looks something like this (`kMinimumZoomScale` and `kMaximumZoomScale` are `#define`'s at the top of the class):

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
        self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        self.bouncesZoom = YES;
        self.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
        self.delegate = self;

        self.minimumZoomScale = kMinimumZoomScale;
        self.maximumZoomScale = kMaximumZoomScale;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Then I implement the standard `UIScrollView` delegate methods for zooming. My `ContentView` class has a property called zoomScale that tells it what scale to use for displaying its content. It uses that in its `drawRect` method to resize the content as appropriate.

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
    return contentView;
}


- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
    CGFloat oldZoomScale = contentView.zoomScale;
    CGSize size = self.bounds.size;

    // Figure out where the scroll view was centered so that we can
    // fix up its offset after adjusting the scaling
    CGPoint contentCenter = self.contentOffset;
    contentCenter.x += size.width / (oldZoomScale * scale) / 2;
    contentCenter.y += size.height / (oldZoomScale * scale) / 2;

    CGFloat newZoomScale = scale * oldZoomScale;
    newZoomScale = MAX(newZoomScale, kMinimumZoomscale);
    newZoomScale = MIN(newZoomScale, kMaximumZoomscale);

    // Set the scroll view's zoom scale back to 1 and adjust its minimum and maximum
    // to allow the expected amount of zooming.
    self.zoomScale = 1.0;
    self.minimumZoomScale = kMinimumZoomScale / newZoomScale;
    self.maximumZoomScale = kMaximumZoomScale / newZoomScale;

    // Tell the contentView about its new scale. My contentView.zoomScale setter method
    // calls setNeedsDisplay, but you could also call it here
    contentView.zoomScale = newZoomScale;

    // My ContentView class overrides sizeThatFits to give its expected size with
    // zoomScale taken into account
    CGRect newContentSize = [contentView sizeThatFits];

    // update the content view's frame and the scroll view's contentSize with the new size
    contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, newContentSize.width, newContentSize.height);
    self.contentSize = newContentSize;

    // Figure out the new contentOffset so that the contentView doesn't appear to move
    CGPoint newContentOffset = CGPointMake(contentCenter.x - size.width / newZoomScale / 2,
                                           contentCenter.y - size.height / newZoomScale / 2);
    newContentOffset.x = MIN(newContentOffset.x, newContentSize.width - size.width);
    newContentOffset.x = MAX(0, newContentOffset.x);
    newContentOffset.y = MIN(newContentOffset.y, newContentSize.height - .size.height);
    newContentOffset.y = MAX(0, newContentOffset.y);
    [self setContentOffset:newContentOffset animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution! This solves [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970988/how-to-draw-on-a-non-transformed-context-while-zoomed-in-a-catiledlayer). Could you leave a link to your answer there, so I can give you proper credit for answering it?

Comment: If this method is used to zoom a CATiledLayer, the tile-cache needs to be cleared before calling setNeedsDisplay. A solution for clearing the CATiledLayerCache is available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274680/clear-catiledlayers-cache-when-changing-images)

Comment: can you please explain the property of the contentSize and how it gets set and what it actually is. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have an image view and on top of the image view I have several other imageviews. This is the implementation I came up with and works fine:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(double)scale{
    NSLog(@"finished zooming");

    NSLog(@"position x :%f",pin1.frame.origin.x);
    NSLog(@"position y :%f",pin1.frame.origin.y);


    CGRect frame = pin1.frame;
    frame.origin.x = pin1.frame.origin.x * scale;
    frame.origin.y = pin1.frame.origin.y * scale;
    pin1.frame = frame;

    NSLog(@"position x new :%f",pin1.frame.origin.x);
    NSLog(@"position y new:%f",pin1.frame.origin.y);

}
```