# CATiledLayer and UIScrollView, caching old data for some zoom levels

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I have a CATiledLayer set up to dynamically re-draw some graphics I'm creating with Quartz.

This view is added as the content view of a scroll view, and as I scroll and zoom the graphic is redrawing at the proper resolution and doing exactly as I expected.

My problem is that If I change the values that generate the graphic (it is a visualization of a graph like structure), then setNeedsDisplay on the view, the changes will apply and be shown at some zoom levels, but if you zoom out it will show the old graphic that was generated. Zooming in again goes back to the proper graphic.

I assume that the different zoom levels in the tiled layer are being cached, and so the update isn't being applied to the already cached zoom levels.

My question is, if this is the case, is there any way to force the CATiledLayer to redraw not from the cached data? And if not, does anyone know what could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still having this issue but I have run into it myself recently. This seems like the same issue from [Clear CATiledLayers Cache When Changing Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274680/clear-catiledlayers-cache-when-changing-images) The answer seems to be to set the layer.content to nil and then call for a refresh with setNeedsDisplay or setNeedsDisplayInRect:. So wherever you would have called setNeedsDisplay to refresh the view after wanting it cleared you would instead use:

```
layer.content = nil;
[layer setNeedsDisplay];
```

This seems to work for me though in the comments for the answer of the above linked question there are warnings against directly setting the layer.content property. Aside from possibly removing and re-adding the layer though I have not been able to come up with any other options.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm not using CATiledLayer for this anymore, but great to know for future projects. I'll try it out :).